# How to Graph an Asymptote on a Plot?

Tags: plotting, legending

I am currently plotting the following three functions, which show a discontinuity at `0.7993` (approximately). I am generating the plot with the following code:

```
Plot[{(p (((3 p)/8 + 5/8) p - 3/16) - 15/32)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4), (p (1/4 p (p + 2) - 1/8) - 3/8)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4), (p (1/8 p (p + 3) - 1/16) - 9/32)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4)}, {p, 0, 1}]
```

And I am finding the asymptote at `0.7993` by using:

```
Select[Solve[p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4 == 0, p], 
 Element[p /. #1, Reals] &]
```

The output I get is this one:

[image: Output]

Then my question is: **how can I mark the asymptote with a dotted gray line (or alike)?**

Also, would anyone be so kind to briefly give me a hint on how to add labels to the functions and a legend, such as "function 1", "function 2", "function 3", or similar?

Comment: Search for PlotPiecewise on this site

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
p0 = p /. Select[Solve[p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4 == 0, p], Element[p /. #1, Reals] &][[1]]
```

one can do

```
Plot[{(p (((3 p)/8 + 5/8) p - 3/16) - 15/32)/(p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 
     3/4), (p (1/4 p (p + 2) - 1/8) - 3/8)/(p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 
     3/4), (p (1/8 p (p + 3) - 1/16) - 9/32)/(p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 
     3/4)}, {p, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {p0}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Gray], PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

For instructive examples on how to modify the legend, see [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html); for various options for plotting, see [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. As soon as I can, I will accept your (perfect) answer. On top of all this, would it be possible to get some hints on how to modify the aspect, the content and the location of the legend, as well as the dimension of the y-axis?

Comment: The _Basic Examples_ of [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) are very instructive. What do you mean by "_modify (...) the dimension of the y-axis"_?

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that link asap. What I mean that is to make the plot in such a way that we get to see the y-axis from -1 to 1, instead of seeing it from 0 to 1, as it is now (for example). Does it make better sense now? I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: See the edited answer for a few additional details.